# Как совместить значения из двух функций в другую функцию ? И вывести результат на экран

Tags: python, функции, python-3.5

Всем привет. Если можете пожалуйста более детально объяснить как работать с параметрами и собственными функциями. Учу Питон недавно, уж очень я застрял я на этой теме, а объяснения в интернете слишком терминологичные и пока непонятные.

```
import random

def numb():
   print('Вычисление значений в кубе из рандомных чисел.')
   a = random.randint(1,100)
   return a

def vizual():
   print('Сколько значений желаете вывести на экран ?')
   count = input()
   return count

def Otvet(a,count):
    for num in range (case):
        suma = int(a)**2
        print('#', (case +1) , 'Номер в кубе :', a)
        print(suma)

num = numb()
case = vizual()
Otvet(num,case)
```

Comment: Нужно сюда скопировать главу из учебника или о чем вопрос?

Comment: `return count` заменить на `return int(count)` и все заработает, а что конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Непонятно именно как влияет параметры внутри собственных функций, и как использовать чтобы получить желаемый результат. Как я понял в скобках вводится переменная которую хотим вычислить, дальше мы можем результат функций записать в другую переменную вне локальной области, но именно процесс , непонятен, как вычислить, зачем они нужны, и как с ними работать ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def numb(n):
    print('Вычисление значений в кубе из рандомных чисел.')
#   a = random.randint(1,100)
    a = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)]
    return a

def vizual():
   print('Сколько значений желаете вывести на экран ?')
   count = int(input())                                       # int
   return count

def Otvet(a, count):
#    for num in range (case):
    for num in a:
        suma = num ** 3 
        print('#', num , ' в кубе :', suma)


case = vizual()

num = numb(case)

Otvet(num, case)
```

---

```
Сколько значений желаете вывести на экран ?
3
Вычисление значений в кубе из рандомных чисел.
# 99  в кубе : 970299
# 27  в кубе : 19683
# 94  в кубе : 830584
```